# How to disable Braintree Payment Method for Admin but enabled on Frontend?

Tags: magento2.3, admin, payment-methods, braintree

I have to disable Braintree Payment Method for Admin but it will be enabled on Frontend as the Client's requirement.

I am not able to figure out as the IsAvailable method to disable payment solution is not working in the Braintree payment method.

Please Help!